# How to implement kalman filter on gps data in R

Tags: r, gps, kalman-filter

I'm very new to analysing GPS data so please be patient.

I have a series of GPS fixes at 1 second intervals (there are some instances where fixes have failed to record) and would like to smooth the data to minimise errors by using R and was wondering whether there is a straightforward way to do so?

Here is some of the data (I have >50000 fixes per individual)

```
Date     Time    Latitude    Longitude   Altitude    Speed
12/06/2017   12:25:00   50.774715   -3.932923   165.13  14904
12/06/2017   12:25:01   50.774742   -3.932912   164.44  5940
12/06/2017   12:25:02   50.774773   -3.932896   163.81  1188
12/06/2017   12:25:04   50.774792   -3.932908   163.53  2880
12/06/2017   12:25:05   50.774803   -3.932924   163.5   0
12/06/2017   12:25:06   50.774803   -3.932924   163.5   0
12/06/2017   12:25:07   50.774803   -3.932924   163.5   0
12/06/2017   12:25:08   50.774803   -3.932924   163.5   0
```

Comment: This is not going to be much of an answer, since like you, I am just learning about this problem.  But you might be interested in [blog post](http://boazsobrado.com/blog/2017/08/29/implementing-a-kalman-filter-in-r-for-android-gps-measurements/), which briefly describes an implementation of a kalman filter in R.  The data used are slightly different, since the author uses accuracy and does not have speed.  If you have found a better answer, post it back here so we can all learn from it!

Comment: Is that all the data you have? No Heading, Yaw-Rate, wheel-velocities etc? Without any of that I dont think a Kalman Filter is reasonable, as you have to predict the next location based on some additional info, like sensor-data. With your dataset you could only predict the next location based on timesteps and velocity, whereas velocity is probably calculated with the gps-signal. So you're lacking additional information.